# HTML input range slider is affecting the wrong D3 chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have two D3 edge bundle charts, one on top of the other (CSS grid). For the top chart (id: edgeB) I have a div input style slider that changes the tension (amount of curve) of the node lines. It should affect the top chart only. Currently, the slider associated with the top chart is affecting the bottom most chart (id: edgeBTwo). I've tried including the correct div id but it seems to have no effect. I'm thinking that it is affecting the most recently created D3 chart but I'm not sure how to change this behavior.

Here is all of my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="icon" type="globe_icon.png">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <style type="text/css">

        body {
            padding: 90px;
            margin: 0px;
            height: 100%;
        }
        html,
        .grid-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr;
            grid-template-rows: auto auto;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            padding: 10px;
            grid-row-gap: 10px;
          }
        .grid-item1 {
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            border: 5px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
            padding: 15px;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: left;
            grid-row-gap: 10px;
            font: 8pt "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }
        .grid-item2 {
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            border: 5px solid rgba(234, 0, 255, 0.8);
            padding: 15px;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: left;
            grid-row-gap: 10px;
            font: 8pt "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }
        .wrapword {
            white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
            white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap;          /* Chrome & Safari */ 
            white-space: -pre-wrap;                 /* Opera 4-6 */
            white-space: -o-pre-wrap;               /* Opera 7 */
            white-space: pre-wrap;                  /* CSS3 */
            word-wrap: break-word;                  /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
            word-break: break-all;
            white-space: normal;
        }
        path.arc {
            cursor: move;
            fill: #000000;
          }
          .node {
            font: 300 9 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);
          }
          .node:hover {
            fill: rgb(132, 236, 255);
          }
          .node:hover,
          .node--source,
          .node--target {
            font-weight: 700;
          }
          .link {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #1f77b4;
            stroke-opacity: .5;
            pointer-events: none;
          }
          .link.source, .link.target {
            stroke-opacity: .8;
            stroke-width: 2px;
          }
          .node.target {
            fill: #d62728 !important;
          }
          .link.source {
            stroke: #d62728;
          }
          .node.source {
            fill: #00ff40;
          }
          .link.target {
            stroke: #00ff40;
          }
    </style>


</head>
<body>

    <div class="grid-container"></div>
        <div class="grid-item1" id="edgeB">
            <div id="edgeB" style="position:absolute;bottom: 2%;;font-size:16px;">Tension: <input style="position:relative;top:3px;" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="85"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="packages.js"></script>
            <script>
            (function chart1(){
                color = d3.scale.category10(); 
                var w = 700,
                    h = 700,
                    rx = w / 2.1,
                    ry = h / 2.1,
                    m0,
                    rotate = 0
                  pi = Math.PI;
            
                var splines = [];
            
                var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
                    .size([360, ry - 180])
                    .sort(function(a, b) {
                        return d3.ascending(a.key, b.key);
                    });
            
                var bundle = d3.layout.bundle();
            
                var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
                    .interpolate("bundle")
                    .tension(.8)
                    .radius(function(d) {
                        return d.y;
                    })
                    .angle(function(d) {
                        return d.x / 180 * Math.PI;
                    });
            
                // Chrome 15 bug: <http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=98951>
                var div = d3.select("#edgeB")
                
                    .style("width", w + "px")
                    .style("height", w + "px")
                    .style("position", "relative");
            
                var svg = div.append("svg:svg")
                    .attr("width", 700)
                    .attr("height", 700)
                    .append("svg:g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + rx + "," + ry + ")");
            
                svg.append("svg:path")
                    .attr("class", "arc")
                    .attr("d", d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(ry - 180).innerRadius(0).startAngle(0).endAngle(2 * Math.PI))
                    .on("mousedown", mousedown);
            
                d3.json("flare_year.json", function(classes) {
            
                    var nodes = cluster.nodes(packages.root(classes)),
                        links = packages.imports(nodes),
                        splines = bundle(links);
            
                    var path = svg.selectAll("path.link")
                        .data(links)
                        .enter().append("svg:path")
                        .attr("class", function(d) {
                            return "link source-" + d.source.key + " target-" + d.target.key;
                        })
                        .attr("d", function(d, i) {
                            return line(splines[i]);
                        });
            
                    var groupData = svg.selectAll("g.group")
                        .data(nodes.filter(function(d) {
                          return (d.key == '1970-1979' || d.key == '1980-1989' || d.key == '1990-1999' || d.key == '2000-2009' || d.key == '2010-2019') && d.children;
          
                        }))
                        .enter().append("group")
                        .attr("class", "group");
            
                    var groupArc = d3.svg.arc()
                        .innerRadius(ry - 177)
                        .outerRadius(ry - 157)
                        .startAngle(function(d) {
                            return (findStartAngle(d.__data__.children) - 2.3) * pi / 180;
                        })
                        .endAngle(function(d) {
                            return (findEndAngle(d.__data__.children) + 2.3) * pi / 180;
                        });        
            
                    svg.selectAll("g.arc")
                        .data(groupData[0])
                        .enter().append("svg:path")
                        .attr("d", groupArc)
                        .attr("class", "groupArc")
                        .attr("id", function(d, i) {console.log(d.__data__.key); return d.__data__.key;})
                        .style("fill", function(d, i) {return color(i);})
                        .style("fill-opacity", 0.5)
                        .each(function(d,i) {
            
                            var firstArcSection = /(^.+?)L/;
            
                            var newArc = firstArcSection.exec( d3.select(this).attr("d") )[1];
            
                            newArc = newArc.replace(/,/g , " ");
            
                            svg.append("path")
                                .attr("class", "hiddenArcs")
                                .attr("id", "hidden"+d.__data__.key)
                                .attr("d", newArc)
                                .style("fill", "none");
                        });
    
                    svg.selectAll(".arcText")
                        .data(groupData[0])
                        .enter().append("text")
                        .attr("class", "arcText")
                        .attr("dy", 12)
                        .append("textPath")
                        .attr("startOffset","50%")
                        .style("text-anchor","middle")
                        .attr("xlink:href",function(d,i){return "#hidden" + d.__data__.key;})
                        .text(function(d){return d.__data__.key;});    
            
                    svg.selectAll("g.node")
                        .data(nodes.filter(function(n) {
                            return !n.children;
                        }))
                        .enter().append("svg:g")
                        .attr("class", "node")
                        .attr("id", function(d) {
                            return "node-" + d.key;
                        })
                        .attr("transform", function(d) {
                            return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")";
                        })
                        .append("svg:text")
                        .attr("dx", function(d) {
                            return d.x < 180 ? 25 : -25;
                        })
                        .attr("dy", ".31em")
                        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
                            return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end";
                        })
                        .attr("transform", function(d) {
                            return d.x < 180 ? null : "rotate(180)";
                        })
                        .text(function(d) {
                            return d.key.replace(/_/g, ' ');
                        })
                        .on("mouseover", mouseover)
                        .on("mouseout", mouseout);
            
                    d3.select("input[type=range]").on("change", function() {
                        line.tension(this.value / 100);
                        path.attr("d", function(d, i) {
                            return line(splines[i]);
                        });
                    });
                });
            
                d3.select(window)
                    .on("mousemove", mousemove)
                    .on("mouseup", mouseup);
            
                    function mouse(e) {
                        return [e.pageX - rx, e.pageY - ry];
                      }
                      
                      function mousedown() {
                        m0 = mouse(d3.event);
                        d3.event.preventDefault();
                      }
                      
                      function mousemove() {
                        if (m0) {
                          var m1 = mouse(d3.event),
                              dm = Math.atan2(cross(m0, m1), dot(m0, m1)) * 180 / Math.PI;
                          div.style("-webkit-transform", "translate3d(0," + (ry - rx) + "px,0)rotate3d(0,0,0," + dm + "deg)translate3d(0," + (rx - ry) + "px,0)");
                        }
                      }
                      
                      function mouseup() {
                        if (m0) {
                          var m1 = mouse(d3.event),
                              dm = Math.atan2(cross(m0, m1), dot(m0, m1)) * 180 / Math.PI;
                      
                          rotate += dm;
                          if (rotate > 360) rotate -= 360;
                          else if (rotate < 0) rotate += 360;
                          m0 = null;
                      
                          div.style("-webkit-transform", "rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg)");
                      
                          svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + rx + "," + ry + ")rotate(" + rotate + ")")
                            .selectAll("g.node text")
                              .attr("dx", function(d) { return (d.x + rotate) % 360 < 180 ? 25 : -25; })
                              .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return (d.x + rotate) % 360 < 180 ? "start" : "end"; })
                              .attr("transform", function(d) { return (d.x + rotate) % 360 < 180 ? null : "rotate(180)"; });
                        }
                      }
            
                function mouseover(d) {
                    svg.selectAll("path.link.target-" + d.key)
                        .classed("target", true)
                        .each(updateNodes("source", true));
            
                    svg.selectAll("path.link.source-" + d.key)
                        .classed("source", true)
                        .each(updateNodes("target", true));
                }
            
                function mouseout(d) {
                    svg.selectAll("path.link.source-" + d.key)
                        .classed("source", false)
                        .each(updateNodes("target", false));
            
                    svg.selectAll("path.link.target-" + d.key)
                        .classed("target", false)
                        .each(updateNodes("source", false));
                }
            
                function updateNodes(name, value) {
                    return function(d) {
                        if (value) this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
                        svg.select("#node-" + d[name].key).classed(name, value);
                    };
                }
            
                function cross(a, b) {
                    return a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0];
                }
            
                function dot(a, b) {
                    return a[0] * b[0] + a[1] * b[1];
                }
            
                function findStartAngle(children) {
                    var min = children[0].x;
                    children.forEach(function(d) {
                        if (d.x < min)
                            min = d.x;
                    });
                    return min;
                }
            
                function findEndAngle(children) {
                    var max = children[0].x;
                    children.forEach(function(d) {
                        if (d.x > max)
                            max = d.x;
                    });
                    return max;
                }}())
            </script>     
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item2" id="edgeBTwo">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="packages.js"></script>
            <script>
            (function chart2(){
                color = d3.scale.category10(); 
                var w = 700,
                    h = 700,
                    rx = w / 2.1,
                    ry = h / 2.1,
                    m0,
                    rotate = 0
                  pi = Math.PI;
            
                var splines = [];
            
                var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
                    .size([360, ry - 180])
                    .sort(function(a, b) {
                        return d3.ascending(a.key, b.key);
                    });
            
                var bundle = d3.layout.bundle();
            
                var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
                    .interpolate("bundle")
                    .tension(.8)
                    .radius(function(d) {
                        return d.y;
                    })
                    .angle(function(d) {
                        return d.x / 180 * Math.PI;
                    });
            
                // Chrome 15 bug: <http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=98951>
                var div = d3.select("#edgeBTwo")
                
                    .style("width", w + "px")
                    .style("height", w + "px")
                    .style("position", "relative");
            
                var svg = div.append("svg:svg")
                    .attr("width", 700)
                    .attr("height", 700)
                    .append("svg:g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + rx + "," + ry + ")");
            
                svg.append("svg:path")
                    .attr("class", "arc")
                    .attr("d", d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(ry - 180).innerRadius(0).startAngle(0).endAngle(2 * Math.PI))
                    .on("mousedown", mousedown);
            
                d3.json("flare_test.json", function(classes) {
            
                    var nodes = cluster.nodes(packages.root(classes)),
                        links = packages.imports(nodes),
                        splines = bundle(links);
            
                    var path = svg.selectAll("path.link")
                        .data(links)
                        .enter().append("svg:path")
                        .attr("class", function(d) {
                            return "link source-" + d.source.key + " target-" + d.target.key;
                        })
                        .attr("d", function(d, i) {
                            return line(splines[i]);
                        });
            
                    var groupData = svg.selectAll("g.group")
                        .data(nodes.filter(function(d) {
                          return (d.key == '1970-1979' || d.key == 'Low' || d.key == 'Medium' || d.key == 'High') && d.children;
          
                        }))
                        .enter().append("group")
                        .attr("class", "group");
            
                    var groupArc = d3.svg.arc()
                        .innerRadius(ry - 177)
                        .outerRadius(ry - 157)
                        .startAngle(function(d) {
                            return (findStartAngle(d.__data__.children) - 2.3) * pi / 180;
                        })
                        .endAngle(function(d) {
                            return (findEndAngle(d.__data__.children) + 2.3) * pi / 180;
                        });        
            
                    svg.selectAll("g.arc")
                        .data(groupData[0])
                        .enter().append("svg:path")
                        .attr("d", groupArc)
                        .attr("class", "groupArc")
                        .attr("id", function(d, i) {console.log(d.__data__.key); return d.__data__.key;})
                        .style("fill", function(d, i) {return color(i);})
                        .style("fill-opacity", 0.5)
                        .each(function(d,i) {
            
                            var firstArcSection = /(^.+?)L/;
            
                            var newArc = firstArcSection.exec( d3.select(this).attr("d") )[1];
            
                            newArc = newArc.replace(/,/g , " ");
            
                            svg.append("path")
                                .attr("class", "hiddenArcs")
                                .attr("id", "hidden"+d.__data__.key)
                                .attr("d", newArc)
                                .style("fill", "none");
                        });
                    svg.selectAll(".arcText")
                        .data(groupData[0])
                        .enter().append("text")
                        .attr("class", "arcText")
                        .attr("dy", 12)
                        .append("textPath")
                        .attr("startOffset","50%")
                        .style("text-anchor","middle")
                        .attr("xlink:href",function(d,i){return "#hidden" + d.__data__.key;})
                        .text(function(d){return d.__data__.key;});    
            
                    svg.selectAll("g.node")
                        .data(nodes.filter(function(n) {
                            return !n.children;
                        }))
                        .enter().append("svg:g")
                        .attr("class", "node")
                        .attr("id", function(d) {
                            return "node-" + d.key;
                        })
                        .attr("transform", function(d) {
                            return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")";
                        })
                        .append("svg:text")
                        .attr("dx", function(d) {
                            return d.x < 180 ? 25 : -25;
                        })
                        .attr("dy", ".31em")
                        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
                            return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end";
                        })
                        .attr("transform", function(d) {
                            return d.x < 180 ? null : "rotate(180)";
                        })
                        .text(function(d) {
                            return d.key.replace(/_/g, ' ');
                        })
                        .on("mouseover", mouseover)
                        .on("mouseout", mouseout);
            
                    d3.select("input[type=range]").on("change", function() {
                        line.tension(this.value / 100);
                        path.attr("d", function(d, i) {
                            return line(splines[i]);
                        });
                    });
                });
            
                d3.select(window)
                    .on("mousemove", mousemove)
                    .on("mouseup", mouseup);
            
                    function mouse(e) {
                        return [e.pageX - rx, e.pageY - ry];
                      }
                      
                      function mousedown() {
                        m0 = mouse(d3.event);
                        d3.event.preventDefault();
                      }
                      
                      function mousemove() {
                        if (m0) {
                          var m1 = mouse(d3.event),
                              dm = Math.atan2(cross(m0, m1), dot(m0, m1)) * 180 / Math.PI;
                          div.style("-webkit-transform", "translate3d(0," + (ry - rx) + "px,0)rotate3d(0,0,0," + dm + "deg)translate3d(0," + (rx - ry) + "px,0)");
                        }
                      }
                      
                      function mouseup() {
                        if (m0) {
                          var m1 = mouse(d3.event),
                              dm = Math.atan2(cross(m0, m1), dot(m0, m1)) * 180 / Math.PI;
                      
                          rotate += dm;
                          if (rotate > 360) rotate -= 360;
                          else if (rotate < 0) rotate += 360;
                          m0 = null;
                      
                          div.style("-webkit-transform", "rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg)");
                      
                          svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + rx + "," + ry + ")rotate(" + rotate + ")")
                            .selectAll("g.node text")
                              .attr("dx", function(d) { return (d.x + rotate) % 360 < 180 ? 25 : -25; })
                              .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return (d.x + rotate) % 360 < 180 ? "start" : "end"; })
                              .attr("transform", function(d) { return (d.x + rotate) % 360 < 180 ? null : "rotate(180)"; });
                        }
                      }
                function mouseover(d) {
                    svg.selectAll("path.link.target-" + d.key)
                        .classed("target", true)
                        .each(updateNodes("source", true));
            
                    svg.selectAll("path.link.source-" + d.key)
                        .classed("source", true)
                        .each(updateNodes("target", true));
                }
            
                function mouseout(d) {
                    svg.selectAll("path.link.source-" + d.key)
                        .classed("source", false)
                        .each(updateNodes("target", false));
            
                    svg.selectAll("path.link.target-" + d.key)
                        .classed("target", false)
                        .each(updateNodes("source", false));
                }
            
                function updateNodes(name, value) {
                    return function(d) {
                        if (value) this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
                        svg.select("#node-" + d[name].key).classed(name, value);
                    };
                }
                function cross(a, b) {
                    return a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0];
                }
                function dot(a, b) {
                    return a[0] * b[0] + a[1] * b[1];
                }
                function findStartAngle(children) {
                    var min = children[0].x;
                    children.forEach(function(d) {
                        if (d.x < min)
                            min = d.x;
                    });
                    return min;
                }
                function findEndAngle(children) {
                    var max = children[0].x;
                    children.forEach(function(d) {
                        if (d.x > max)
                            max = d.x;
                    });
                    return max;
                }}());
            </script>     
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my packages.js file and both data files needed to run the above code:

packages.js

```
(function() {
  packages = {

    // Lazily construct the package hierarchy from class names.
    root: function(classes) {
      var map = {};

      function find(name, data) {
        var node = map[name], i;
        if (!node) {
          node = map[name] = data || {name: name, children: []};
          if (name.length) {
            node.parent = find(name.substring(0, i = name.lastIndexOf(".")));
            node.parent.children.push(node);
            node.key = name.substring(i + 1);
          }
        }
        return node;
      }

      classes.forEach(function(d) {
        find(d.name, d);
      });

      return map[""];
    },

    // Return a list of imports for the given array of nodes.
    imports: function(nodes) {
      var map = {},
          imports = [];

      // Compute a map from name to node.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        map[d.name] = d;
      });

      // For each import, construct a link from the source to target node.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        if (d.imports) d.imports.forEach(function(i) {
          imports.push({source: map[d.name], target: map[i]});
        });
      });

      return imports;
    }

  };
})();
```

flare_year.json

```
[
    {
        "name": "root.2010-2019.A",
        "imports": [
            "root.1990-1999.B",
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "root.1990-1999.B",
        "imports": [
            "root.2010-2019.A",
        ]
    }
]
```

flare_test.json

```
[
    {
        "name": "root.High.A",
        "imports": [
            "root.Medium.F",
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "root.Medium.F",
        "imports": [
            "root.High.A",
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a simple issue but took me some time to figure out.

What you are doing wrong is that you are assigning the onChange Event Handler on (input[type="range"]) in chart1 and again assigning it in chart2 on the same node. Event Listener assigned later will always be called.

You need to have **seperate inputs for range and corresponding handlers or if you want to assign a same handler, add a dropdown to select which chart to change and get value of that dropdown in the event handler.**

Your fixed code below:

```js
(function() {
  packages = {

    // Lazily construct the package hierarchy from class names.
    root: function(classes) {
      var map = {};

      function find(name, data) {
        var node = map[name],
          i;
        if (!node) {
          node = map[name] = data || {
            name: name,
            children: []
          };
          if (name.length) {
            node.parent = find(name.substring(0, i = name.lastIndexOf(".")));
            node.parent.children.push(node);
            node.key = name.substring(i + 1);
          }
        }
        return node;
      }

      classes.forEach(function(d) {
        find(d.name, d);
      });

      return map[""];
    },

    // Return a list of imports for the given array of nodes.
    imports: function(nodes) {
      var map = {},
        imports = [];
      // Compute a map from name to node.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        map[d.name] = d;
      });

      // For each import, construct a link from the source to target node.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        if (d.imports) d.imports.forEach(function(i) {
          imports.push({
            source: map[d.name],
            target: map[i]
          });
        });
      });

      return imports;
    }

  };
})();


(function chart1() {
  color = d3.scale.category10();
  let w = 700,
    h = 700,
    rx = w / 2.1,
    ry = h / 2.1,
    m0,
    rotate = 0
  pi = Math.PI;

  let splines = [];

  let cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
    .size([360, ry - 180])
    .sort(function(a, b) {
      return d3.ascending(a.key, b.key);
    });

  let bundle = d3.layout.bundle();

  let line = d3.svg.line.radial()
    .interpolate("bundle")
    .tension(.8)
    .radius(function(d) {
      return d.y;
    })
    .angle(function(d) {
      return d.x / 180 * Math.PI;
    });

  // Chrome 15 bug: <http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=98951>
  let div = d3.select("#edgeB")

    .style("width", w + "px")
    .style("height", w + "px")
    .style("position", "relative");

  let svg = div.append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", 700)
    .attr("height", 700)
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + rx + "," + ry + ")");

  svg.append("svg:path")
    .attr("class", "arc")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(ry - 180).innerRadius(0).startAngle(0).endAngle(2 * Math.PI))
    .on("mousedown", mousedown);

  {
    let classes = [{
        "name": "root.2010-2019.A",
        "imports": [
          "root.1990-1999.B",
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "root.1990-1999.B",
        "imports": [
          "root.2010-2019.A",
        ]
      }
    ];


    let nodes = cluster.nodes(packages.root(classes)),
      links = packages.imports(nodes),
      splines = bundle(links);

    let path = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links)
      .enter().append("svg:path")
      .attr("class", function(d) {
        return "link source-" + d.source.key + " target-" + d.target.key;
      })
      .attr("d", function(d, i) {
        return line(splines[i]);
      });

    let groupData = svg.selectAll("g.group")
      .data(nodes.filter(function(d) {
        return (d.key == '1970-1979' || d.key == '1980-1989' || d.key == '1990-1999' || d.key == '2000-2009' || d.key == '2010-2019') && d.children;

      }))
      .enter().append("group")
      .attr("class", "group");

    let groupArc = d3.svg.arc()
      .innerRadius(ry - 177)
      .outerRadius(ry - 157)
      .startAngle(function(d) {
        return (findStartAngle(d.__data__.children) - 2.3) * pi / 180;
      })
      .endAngle(function(d) {
        return (findEndAngle(d.__data__.children) + 2.3) * pi / 180;
      });

    svg.selectAll("g.arc")
      .data(groupData[0])
      .enter().append("svg:path")
      .attr("d", groupArc)
      .attr("class", "groupArc")
      .attr("id", function(d, i) {
        console.log(d.__data__.key);
        return d.__data__.key;
      })
      .style("fill", function(d, i) {
        return color(i);
      })
      .style("fill-opacity", 0.5)
      .each(function(d, i) {

        let firstArcSection = /(^.+?)L/;

        let newArc = firstArcSection.exec(d3.select(this).attr("d"))[1];

        newArc = newArc.replace(/,/g, " ");

        svg.append("path")
          .attr("class", "hiddenArcs")
          .attr("id", "hidden" + d.__data__.key)
          .attr("d", newArc)
          .style("fill", "none");
      });

    svg.selectAll(".arcText")
      .data(groupData[0])
      .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "arcText")
      .attr("dy", 12)
      .append("textPath")
      .attr("startOffset", "50%")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) {
        return "#hidden" + d.__data__.key;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.__data__.key;
      });

    svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes.filter(function(n) {
        return !n.children;
      }))
      .enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("id", function(d) {
        return "node-" + d.key;
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")";
      })
      .append("svg:text")
      .attr("dx", function(d) {
        return d.x < 180 ? 25 : -25;
      })
      .attr("dy", ".31em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
        return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end";
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return d.x < 180 ? null : "rotate(180)";
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.key.replace(/_/g, ' ');
      })
      .on("mouseover", mouseover)
      .on("mouseout", mouseout);

    d3.select("input[type=range]").on("change", function() {
      console.log(line);
      line.tension(this.value / 100);
      path.attr("d", function(d, i) {
        return line(splines[i]);
      });
    });
  };

  d3.select(window)
    .on("mousemove", mousemove)
    .on("mouseup", mouseup);

  function mouse(e) {
    return [e.pageX - rx, e.pageY - ry];
  }

  function mousedown() {
    m0 = mouse(d3.event);
    d3.event.preventDefault();
  }

  function mousemove() {
    if (m0) {
      var m1 = mouse(d3.event),
        dm = Math.atan2(cross(m0, m1), dot(m0, m1)) * 180 / Math.PI;
      div.style("-webkit-transform", "translate3d(0," + (ry - rx) + "px,0)rotate3d(0,0,0," + dm + "deg)translate3d(0," + (rx - ry) + "px,0)");
    }
  }

  function mouseup() {
    if (m0) {
      var m1 = mouse(d3.event),
        dm = Math.atan2(cross(m0, m1), dot(m0, m1)) * 180 / Math.PI;

      rotate += dm;
      if (rotate > 360) rotate -= 360;
      else if (rotate < 0) rotate += 360;
      m0 = null;

      div.style("-webkit-transform", "rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg)");

      svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + rx + "," + ry + ")rotate(" + rotate + ")")
        .selectAll("g.node text")
        .attr("dx", function(d) {
          return (d.x + rotate) % 360 < 180 ? 25 : -25;
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return (d.x + rotate) % 360 < 180 ? "start" : "end";
        })
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return (d.x + rotate) % 360 < 180 ? null : "rotate(180)";
        });
    }
  }

  function mouseover(d) {
    svg.selectAll("path.link.target-" + d.key)
      .classed("target", true)
      .each(updateNodes("source", true));

    svg.selectAll("path.link.source-" + d.key)
      .classed("source", true)
      .each(updateNodes("target", true));
  }

  function mouseout(d) {
    svg.selectAll("path.link.source-" + d.key)
      .classed("source", false)
      .each(updateNodes("target", false));

    svg.selectAll("path.link.target-" + d.key)
      .classed("target", false)
      .each(updateNodes("source", false));
  }

  function updateNodes(name, value) {
    return function(d) {
      if (value) this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
      svg.select("#node-" + d[name].key).classed(name, value);
    };
  }

  function cross(a, b) {
    return a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0];
  }

  function dot(a, b) {
    return a[0] * b[0] + a[1] * b[1];
  }

  function findStartAngle(children) {
    var min = children[0].x;
    children.forEach(function(d) {
      if (d.x < min)
        min = d.x;
    });
    return min;
  }

  function findEndAngle(children) {
    var max = children[0].x;
    children.forEach(function(d) {
      if (d.x > max)
        max = d.x;
    });
    return max;
  }
}());



(function chart2() {
  color = d3.scale.category10();
  var w = 700,
    h = 700,
    rx = w / 2.1,
    ry = h / 2.1,
    m0,
    rotate = 0
  pi = Math.PI;

  var splines = [];

  var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
    .size([360, ry - 180])
    .sort(function(a, b) {
      return d3.ascending(a.key, b.key);
    });

  var bundle = d3.layout.bundle();

  var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
    .interpolate("bundle")
    .tension(.8)
    .radius(function(d) {
      return d.y;
    })
    .angle(function(d) {
      return d.x / 180 * Math.PI;
    });

  // Chrome 15 bug: <http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=98951>
  var div = d3.select("#edgeBTwo")

    .style("width", w + "px")
    .style("height", w + "px")
    .style("position", "relative");

  var svg = div.append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", 700)
    .attr("height", 700)
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + rx + "," + ry + ")");

  svg.append("svg:path")
    .attr("class", "arc")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(ry - 180).innerRadius(0).startAngle(0).endAngle(2 * Math.PI))
    .on("mousedown", mousedown);

 {
    let classes = [
    {
        "name": "root.High.A",
        "imports": [
            "root.Medium.F",
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "root.Medium.F",
        "imports": [
            "root.High.A",
        ]
    }
];
    var nodes = cluster.nodes(packages.root(classes)),
      links = packages.imports(nodes),
      splines = bundle(links);

    var path = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links)
      .enter().append("svg:path")
      .attr("class", function(d) {
        return "link source-" + d.source.key + " target-" + d.target.key;
      })
      .attr("d", function(d, i) {
        return line(splines[i]);
      });

    var groupData = svg.selectAll("g.group")
      .data(nodes.filter(function(d) {
        return (d.key == '1970-1979' || d.key == 'Low' || d.key == 'Medium' || d.key == 'High') && d.children;

      }))
      .enter().append("group")
      .attr("class", "group");

    var groupArc = d3.svg.arc()
      .innerRadius(ry - 177)
      .outerRadius(ry - 157)
      .startAngle(function(d) {
        return (findStartAngle(d.__data__.children) - 2.3) * pi / 180;
      })
      .endAngle(function(d) {
        return (findEndAngle(d.__data__.children) + 2.3) * pi / 180;
      });

    svg.selectAll("g.arc")
      .data(groupData[0])
      .enter().append("svg:path")
      .attr("d", groupArc)
      .attr("class", "groupArc")
      .attr("id", function(d, i) {
        console.log(d.__data__.key);
        return d.__data__.key;
      })
      .style("fill", function(d, i) {
        return color(i);
      })
      .style("fill-opacity", 0.5)
      .each(function(d, i) {

        var firstArcSection = /(^.+?)L/;

        var newArc = firstArcSection.exec(d3.select(this).attr("d"))[1];

        newArc = newArc.replace(/,/g, " ");

        svg.append("path")
          .attr("class", "hiddenArcs")
          .attr("id", "hidden" + d.__data__.key)
          .attr("d", newArc)
          .style("fill", "none");
      });
    svg.selectAll(".arcText")
      .data(groupData[0])
      .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "arcText")
      .attr("dy", 12)
      .append("textPath")
      .attr("startOffset", "50%")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) {
        return "#hidden" + d.__data__.key;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.__data__.key;
      });

    svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes.filter(function(n) {
        return !n.children;
      }))
      .enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("id", function(d) {
        return "node-" + d.key;
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")";
      })
      .append("svg:text")
      .attr("dx", function(d) {
        return d.x < 180 ? 25 : -25;
      })
      .attr("dy", ".31em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
        return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end";
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return d.x < 180 ? null : "rotate(180)";
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.key.replace(/_/g, ' ');
      })
      .on("mouseover", mouseover)
      .on("mouseout", mouseout);

    d3.select("input#inputEdgesec").on("change", function() {
      line.tension(this.value / 100);
      path.attr("d", function(d, i) {
        return line(splines[i]);
      });
    });
  };

  d3.select(window)
    .on("mousemove", mousemove)
    .on("mouseup", mouseup);

  function mouse(e) {
    return [e.pageX - rx, e.pageY - ry];
  }

  function mousedown() {
    m0 = mouse(d3.event);
    d3.event.preventDefault();
  }

  function mousemove() {
    if (m0) {
      var m1 = mouse(d3.event),
        dm = Math.atan2(cross(m0, m1), dot(m0, m1)) * 180 / Math.PI;
      div.style("-webkit-transform", "translate3d(0," + (ry - rx) + "px,0)rotate3d(0,0,0," + dm + "deg)translate3d(0," + (rx - ry) + "px,0)");
    }
  }

  function mouseup() {
    if (m0) {
      var m1 = mouse(d3.event),
        dm = Math.atan2(cross(m0, m1), dot(m0, m1)) * 180 / Math.PI;

      rotate += dm;
      if (rotate > 360) rotate -= 360;
      else if (rotate < 0) rotate += 360;
      m0 = null;

      div.style("-webkit-transform", "rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg)");

      svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + rx + "," + ry + ")rotate(" + rotate + ")")
        .selectAll("g.node text")
        .attr("dx", function(d) {
          return (d.x + rotate) % 360 < 180 ? 25 : -25;
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return (d.x + rotate) % 360 < 180 ? "start" : "end";
        })
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return (d.x + rotate) % 360 < 180 ? null : "rotate(180)";
        });
    }
  }

  function mouseover(d) {
    svg.selectAll("path.link.target-" + d.key)
      .classed("target", true)
      .each(updateNodes("source", true));

    svg.selectAll("path.link.source-" + d.key)
      .classed("source", true)
      .each(updateNodes("target", true));
  }

  function mouseout(d) {
    svg.selectAll("path.link.source-" + d.key)
      .classed("source", false)
      .each(updateNodes("target", false));

    svg.selectAll("path.link.target-" + d.key)
      .classed("target", false)
      .each(updateNodes("source", false));
  }

  function updateNodes(name, value) {
    return function(d) {
      if (value) this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
      svg.select("#node-" + d[name].key).classed(name, value);
    };
  }

  function cross(a, b) {
    return a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0];
  }

  function dot(a, b) {
    return a[0] * b[0] + a[1] * b[1];
  }

  function findStartAngle(children) {
    var min = children[0].x;
    children.forEach(function(d) {
      if (d.x < min)
        min = d.x;
    });
    return min;
  }

  function findEndAngle(children) {
    var max = children[0].x;
    children.forEach(function(d) {
      if (d.x > max)
        max = d.x;
    });
    return max;
  }
}());
```

```css
body {
            padding: 90px;
            margin: 0px;
            height: 100%;
        }
        html,
        .grid-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr;
            grid-template-rows: auto auto;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            padding: 10px;
            grid-row-gap: 10px;
          }
        .grid-item1 {
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            border: 5px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
            padding: 15px;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: left;
            grid-row-gap: 10px;
            font: 8pt "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }
        .grid-item2 {
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            border: 5px solid rgba(234, 0, 255, 0.8);
            padding: 15px;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: left;
            grid-row-gap: 10px;
            font: 8pt "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }
        .wrapword {
            white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
            white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap;          /* Chrome & Safari */ 
            white-space: -pre-wrap;                 /* Opera 4-6 */
            white-space: -o-pre-wrap;               /* Opera 7 */
            white-space: pre-wrap;                  /* CSS3 */
            word-wrap: break-word;                  /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
            word-break: break-all;
            white-space: normal;
        }
        path.arc {
            cursor: move;
            fill: #000000;
          }
          .node {
            font: 300 9 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);
          }
          .node:hover {
            fill: rgb(132, 236, 255);
          }
          .node:hover,
          .node--source,
          .node--target {
            font-weight: 700;
          }
          .link {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #1f77b4;
            stroke-opacity: .5;
            pointer-events: none;
          }
          .link.source, .link.target {
            stroke-opacity: .8;
            stroke-width: 2px;
          }
          .node.target {
            fill: #d62728 !important;
          }
          .link.source {
            stroke: #d62728;
          }
          .node.source {
            fill: #00ff40;
          }
          .link.target {
            stroke: #00ff40;
          }
          .sliderContainer
          {
            display:flex;
            flex-direction:column;
          }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="icon" type="globe_icon.png">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>


</head>
<body>

    <div class="grid-container"></div>
        <div class="grid-item1" id="edgeB">
            <div id="edgeB" style="position:absolute;bottom: 2%;;font-size:16px;"><div class="sliderContainer">Tension: <input style="position:relative;top:3px;" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="85">        Tension for second <input id="inputEdgesec" style="position:relative;top:3px;" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="85">
 </div>        
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
            
            </script>     
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item2" id="edgeBTwo">

        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="packages.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah thank you so much for your help in solving this problem! This will help me a lot moving forward, particularly when adding several charts to a page. Cheers!

Comment: Do you know how to split the div style range line so that there's one line per slider?

Comment: Can you explain with drawing on what you want.

Comment: <div id="edgeB" style="position:absolute;bottom: 2%;;font-size:16px;">Tension: <input id="firstchart" style="position:relative;top:3px;" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="85">        Tension for second <input id="secondchart" style="position:relative;top:3px;" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="85">. Settings for both sliders are one the same line here, is there a way to split them?

Comment: aah thats pretty easy, let me modify that in the above code

Comment: Check the above snippet..is that what you want. You can read some css articles to clarify the basics. That will help you in long term. I have added display:flex and flex direction to column so that they are in same column.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer. The placement of the sliders is fine. I was wanting the line of code itself to be split so that there's one line of code inside the "grid-item3" div relating to the top slider, and one line of code inside the "grid-item4" div relating to the bottom slider. Apologies, you've already helped me a ton! I'll be looking to learn more about CSS/HTML, I think I made a mistake in trying to learn D3 first.

Comment: Ah, I just figured it out! it was relatively simple. Thanks again mate and take care.